# The best way to validate a date in VB>Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to validate a date in VB.Net. I used IsDate() as suggested by Microsoft. However, IsDate("5/1/202") returns a true value. I wanted only a year in the format of yyyy to be valid. So, I modified my code as shown below.

```
Dim ResultDate As DateTime = Nothing
If DateTime.TryParseExact(UserEnteredDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, ResultDate) Then
   'more code here
End if
```

I even tried the following code:

```
If (DateTime.TryParseExact(userEnteredDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, ResultDate) = True 
Or
DateTime.TryParseExact(userEnteredDate, "d/M/yyyy", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, ResultDate) = True 
Or
DateTime.TryParseExact(userEnteredDate, "d/MM/yyyy", 
 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, ResultDate) = True 
Or
DateTime.TryParseExact(userEnteredDate, "dd/M/yyyy", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, ResultDate) = True) 
Then

  'More code here
End If
```

The above code invalidates 5/1/202 as per expectations. The problem is since the customer may enter either 5/1/2022 or 05/02/2022, if they enter 5/1/2022 then it fails. I want to validate to true for both 5/1/2022 or 05/02/2022.

Comment: The first of May, in the year Two Hundred and Two. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @djv Clearly the fact that it's the fifth of January in the year two hundred and two ;)

Comment: What is your exact validation criteria?

Comment: *"which is apparently wrong"* - Why is that wrong?  Do you have some indication of why that date never happened?  Are you expecting some more specific validation logic which you haven't provided?  Something else?

Comment: @Massey. The comments here should set you on the right path. Think about why the year 202 is a year but you don't consider it a year (do you need to validate the year against a valid range?), and how two people may consider one string to represent two different dates (do you need to consider the locale when parsing dates?).

Comment: I modified my question. Thanks!

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yyyySpecifier): `The "yyyy" custom format specifier represents the year with a minimum of four digits. If the year has more than four significant digits, they are included in the result string. If the year has fewer than four digits, the number is padded with leading zeros to produce four digits.`

Comment: `if they enter 5/1/2022 then it fails` - `d/M` covers both `5/1` and `05/01`. Even if it didn't, you still separately check for `d/M` and `dd/MM`, so not sure why you say it would fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the resulting year, in conjunction with [Michael Foster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77290491/1115360) saying to use "d/M/yyyy":

```
Dim userEnteredDate = "31/1/2023"

Dim resultDate As DateTime = Nothing
Dim requiredDateFormat = "d/M/yyyy"

If DateTime.TryParseExact(userEnteredDate, requiredDateFormat,
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, resultDate) AndAlso
     resultDate.Year >= 1000 Then
    'more code here
End If
```

The [`AndAlso`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator) will only look at the `.Year` if the parse succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```vb
"d/M/yyyy"
```

It might solve the specific problem of accepting single digits for day and month. But, as the comments have said, you haven't defined all of the ways a date might go wrong. `"5/1/202"` is, of course, a valid date, but not for your purposes. Why not? Would `"5/1/22022"` be valid for 20,000 years from now?